# Publishing a website with VS 2012 the "old way"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to deploy a VS 2012 web site the way it was possible with VS 2008/2010? What I mean is, compile into a "deployed" folder without all the code files and then either FTP or copy to the server.

I have data driven website (not MVC) plain vanilla that I need to "move" to GoDaddy and boy things have changed both with VS and GoDaddy since I last published a site about 3-4 years ago.

I see the "simplicity" that VS 2012 offers but what complicates things is GoDaddy. Time is pressing, so if there is a way that VS2012 can compile the site so that I can copy it to my destination server manually, please advise.

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: I was expecting a similar behavior as with VS2010 where it compiles the website with all its dlls and strips the code files and whatever else it does into a designated folder on my dev box and allows me to copy it anywhere on any machine. VS2012 adds an unneccessary complexity that I don't understand.